# A question about verb

Tags: verbs

I am quite new to grammar and I read this somewhere.
Micky Mouse was featured in a movie.
Now the answer says Verb is **was featured** not featured?? but why?
thanks

Comment: Hi "The Educator", welcome to EL&U. Regrettably I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Note that this site is "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts".You may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers as a newcomer to English grammar. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: The answer to what? What was the question? Are you asking about the difference between “MM featured in a movie” and “MM was featured in a movie”? Or about whether the verb in the latter sentence is _featured_ or _was featured_?

Comment: In this context, ***to feature*** is one of those verbs that effectively carries the same meaning whether it's used in active or passive constructions. Same as ***They married in church / They were married in church**.* This is an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a passive sentence.
The active sentence would be:

A movie *featured* Mickey Mouse.

So it is easy to see now that the verb is *featured*.
In the passive voice(in this case; the past simple), we add the auxiliary **be** verb, and so the new sentence is:

Micky Mouse *was featured* in a movie.

A verb in the passive voice is always a verb phrase and is always consisted of

1. Auxiliary verb (at least one, depending on the tense)
2. the principle verb in its perfect participle form

Answer (score 0):

> *Micky Mouse was featured in a movie*

What you read is half-right. This is a passive construction. The passive voice prototypically consists of a form of the auxiliary verb "be" followed by a past participle such as "featured" in your example.

Syntactically, though, "was featured" is not a constituent, not 'the verb', for there are two verbs involved here and hence two clauses: the matrix clause "Mickey Mouse was featured in a movie", and the embedded subordinate clause "featured in a movie", which functions as complement of "was".